# Is it Pythonic to use set comprehensions for just side effects?

Tags: python, set-comprehension

Question related to [this which asks about side effects in list comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects).

```py
def side_effects_only(x):
    # ...side effects...
    return # None
```

used as

```
{side_effects_only(x) for x in Y}
# where Y is large...
```

This `shouldn't` generate some giant set if Y is large. Since it is a set with a single `None`. Or ...?

Thanks!

Comment: The set is still built and thrown away. The same reasons there apply here.

Comment: I don't think it would be slow since the set is small, but still a normal loop would be more readable

Comment: If you absolutely cannot spare *two* lines for this, you can even do it on one line: `for x in Y: side_effects_only(x)`. And it's still a character shorter than the set comprehension.

Comment: I just like how comprehensions read :). Hence my question.

Comment: The reason has more to do with clearly stating your *intent* than performance issues (though performance can be *an* important reason). Do you want a set? Use a set comprehension. No? Don't use a set comprehension.

Comment: The general consensus is that that's a bad reason to abuse a comprehension for a loop. You can abuse your own code as much as you like, but most other Python programmers will frown upon you.

Comment: If you absolutely must have something like this (cf. Perl statement modifiers), I would just define a wrapper function like `def __(g): for _ in g: pass`, then write `__(side_effects_only(x) for x in Y)`. It's the generator you want, not the comprehension, and `__` is about the simplest way possible to fully consume an iterator with no additional side effects.

Comment: Oh yeah this is nice!